# How to Create Drop Down Menu For Navigation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

I am trying to create a drop down menu for navigation like in this picture 
[image: Picture]

So far in Ms-Access I have created a navigation form, But I am unable to get a drop down menu. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Image of My navigation form
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by 'drop down menu' - not a simple combobox? Where would you want this drop down menu located?

Comment: @June7 I would like the drop down menu to be in the navigation bar, If you look at my photo of the navigation form, I have New customer and View Customers I would like those two forms to be under a drop down menu. Like in the photo above with the products.

Comment: You say you are trying - so what have you tried? I am not aware of any intrinsic feature of Access that can provide this functionality.

Comment: @June7 I was trying to use macros and searched it up trying to find a way to get it working but was unable to find any resource to get it working.

Comment: @June7 I have managed to get the macros somewhat working, when I right click on a customers navigation, I am now able to get new customers and view customers to show and when you click on them the form will open up in a new tab. What I am trying to do now is to make it so the form opens up in the navigation form. [Image](https://imgur.com/a/B6Ataeo)                             [Marcos](https://imgur.com/a/BQq0EC5). I have gone into the customer button property's gone to other and added mcrAddShortcutMenu to Shortcut Menu Bar

Comment: You should edit question with this relevant info. Post code. Are you using macro or VBA? So now you need to set NavigationTargetName? I did a test. Command button code sets that property but have to click on navigation control tab for the change to display. I never use Navigation Form because coding them is frustrating. I use Tab control. If you want a Navigation Form then why not use it as it was intended? Have a tab for each form and let user choose by clicking on tab. Otherwise, use a normal form/subform and set subform SourceObject.